# Anyone got Airxzip with password working on Air for ios/android?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, unzip, password-encryption

I'm building an app in Flashbuilder and using Airxzip AS3 library to unzip files. The 'set password' feature works fine to read/write on Air for Windows. I can unzip files ok in Air for ios, but get error 'password is not match' when file is encrypted with a password. 
I'm wondering if anyone has managed to get this working before I start to delve into differences between windows/ios in the airxzip/ZipCrypto.as file.
(source can be found here: https://airxzip.googlecode.com/svn-history/r7/trunk/airxzip/src/com/coltware/airxzip/crypt/ZipCrypto.as)
Many thanks and Merry Christmas all!

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to get this working on IOS. Problem seems to have been caused by differences in the way IOS and Windows treat oversize integers. Just made a slight modification in the way 'coltware' adjusted for this.

In the ZipCrypto file 'updateKeys()' function change the values set for variables b1 & b2 to:
var b1:int = 134000000;
var b2:int = 775813;

That appears to bring the calculations into a more stable range.
Hope this helps someone.